# How do I run queries on mongodb database, do some other executions and then render the view in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Initially I have been trying to do it via Promise async await, but unable to arrange them well enough and can't find a suitable example for the same.
Help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Please add relevant part of what you have done. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: what you have tried so far feel free to share your code so it will be help full to us to find out what want wrong

Comment: These two links helped me to understand. (1)  https://www.andyshora.com/promises-angularjs-explained-as-cartoon.html              (2) https://dev.to/nickparsons/javascript-promises-and-why-asyncawait-wins-the-battle-1g8a